# Writing a file to the "Shared with me" folder from Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've created a colab notebook called colab.ipynb in a "Shared with me" folder as shown below:

[image: Shared with me folder in Google Drive]

In this notebook, I read in a csv file that is in a subdirectory under the "Shared with me" folder. To do this, I got the share link from the file and converted it using https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/ to the link used in line 8 of the second cell shown below:

[image: File browser within Colab]

After successfully reading the file, a little wrangling is done in lines 14-20 and then the modified dataframe is written out in line 22.  In the colab file browser, I see the file I've written out.  As a sanity check, I looked under My Drive and verified that the file is visible there as well as shown below:

[image]

What I really want to do is write this file to a subdirectory of the "Shared with me" folder (not the "My Drive" or the "Shared drives" folders) shown in the first screen capture, but it is not currently visible from the colab file browser after doing the mount in the first cell as shown in the second screen capture.  I have Editor permissions on the "Shared with me" folder and have added, edited and deleted files.  So in summary, I can read from a file in the "Shared with me" folder, but I currently don't know how to write to a subdirectory under this folder.  Is there a way to do this?